# Border-top Extending too far

Tags: css, navigation, css-selectors

I've got an interesting one: I was testing methods to get the list-item elements of a nav bar to spread evenly across the length of a nav.  I used the display:table and display: table cell method to get the most even spread and that seemed to work fine.

When I went to add an ::after element so I could add a top-bar and have a smoother on-hover effect, I found that the bar extended past where I wanted it to -- I was trying to have it just to the end of the words "Communication Design".  So I thought I'd just resize the nav container holding my list-elements but because it's a table/table-cell, when the nav resizes, the list-items shink along with it and I can never shore up the last element in the list.

Is there a way to either affect the size of the last table cell or only show a percentage of the ::after element?

Code:

HTML:

```
<h3>Test & Co.</h3>
<p id="title2">Communications Design</p>

<div id="navContainer">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Work</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h3
{
padding-left: 140px;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#title2
{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;
margin-right: 252.5px;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#navContainer
{
//border: 1px solid black;
width: 643px;
margin-left: 140px;
height: 30px;
background: white;
}

#navContainer ul
{
list-style:none;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

#navContainer ul li
{
display: table-cell;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
font-family:arial;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
//border: 1px solid black;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
}

#navContainer ul li::after
{
content: "";
display: block;
float: right;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
height: 1px;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #ccc;
transition: background-color .2s ease;
}

#navContainer ul li:hover::after
{
background: #8c8c8c; 
}

#navContainer ul li:hover
{
color: #A6CFEB;
}
```

Comment: If you want only a % of the `:after` to show...change the width

Comment: Because it is only happening on the 4th child would i target it the following way: #navContainer ul li:nth-child(4)::after{ width: 90%}?

Comment: That would work...or since it's the last one `li:last-child`

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks so much!